# How can I stop to drag the event in previous dates but I also want to show the past events?

Tags: reactjs, fullcalendar

I am working on a react project and using a [FullCalendar](https://www.npmjs.com/package/@fullcalendar/react) but I need to stop drag and drop event in previous days so to achieve this I used [validRange](https://fullcalendar.io/docs/validRange) function. This function shows the date from the current date and hides the past dates and events but I also want to show past events and their dates. How can I do this?

```
<FullCalendar
   plugins={[dayGridPlugin, timeGridPlugin, interactionPlugin]}
   headerToolbar={{
      left: 'prev,next today',
      center: 'title',
      right: 'dayGridMonth,timeGridWeek,timeGridDay'
   }}
   initialView='dayGridMonth'
   editable={true}
   selectable={true}
   selectMirror={true}
   dayMaxEvents={true}
   weekends={this.state.weekendsVisible}
   initialEvents={this.state.list}
   select={this.dateSelectHandle}
   eventClick={(event) => console.log(event)}
/>
```

Answer (score 1):

I used [eventDrop](https://fullcalendar.io/docs/eventDrop) method to achieve what I want with the following:

```
eventDrop={(info) => {
   if (new Date() > info.event._instance.range.start){
      info.revert();
   }
}}
```